# Django TestCase with fixtures causes IntegrityError due to duplicate keys

Tags: django, django-testing, django-nose

I'm having trouble moving away from `django_nose.FastFixtureTestCase` to `django.test.TestCase` (or even the more conservative `django.test.TransactionTestCase`).  I'm using Django 1.7.11 and I'm testing against Postgres 9.2.

I have a `Testcase` class that loads three fixtures files.  The class contains two tests.  If I run each test individually as a single run (`manage test test_file:TestClass.test_name`), they each work.  If I run them together, (`manage test test_file:TestClass`), I get

```
IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '<path>/data.json': Could not load <app>.<Model>(pk=1): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "<app_model_field>_49810fc21046d2e2_uniq"
```

To me it looks like the db isn't actually getting flushed or rolled back between tests since it only happens when I run the tests in a single run.

I've stepped through the Django code and it looks like they *are* getting flushed or rolled back -- depending on whether I'm trying `TestCase` or `TransactionTestCase`.

(I'm moving away from `FastFixtureTestCase` because of https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/issues/220)

What else should I be looking at?  This seems like it should be a simple matter and is right within what `django.test.TestCase` and `Django.test.TransactionTestCase` are designed for.

Edit:

The test class more or less looks like this:

```
class MyTest(django.test.TransactionTestCase):  # or django.test.TestCase                        

    fixtures = ['data1.json', 'data2.json', 'data3.json']                                                      

    def test1(self):    
        return # I simplified it to just this for now.                            

    def test2(self):
        return # I simplified it to just this for now.
```

Update:

I've managed to reproduce this a couple of times with a single test, so I suspect something in the fixture loading code.

Comment: Are you sure the field you have as unique is not duplicated in the fixtures?

Comment: Given that the tests work in isolation, I would say yes, I am sure.  They've also been recently dumped/created from the development db.

Comment: How are you loading the fixtures? Could you post the test class?

Comment: Please show fixtures and tests that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I won't be able to in its current form as the data and structures are not mine to share.  I can try reproducing this out of my app, but I'm hoping to find the root cause inside of it instead - hoping there is something obvious wrong that is a common problem.

Comment: What is really odd about this is I tried overriding TestCase._pre_setup() to dump the list of objects in the model that is having the conflict -- the list is empty.  If I understand the code, this is immediately prior to loading the fixtures.  It is as if the db is empty, but the index still has a conflict.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of my basic assumptions was that my db was clean for every `TestCase`.  Tracing into the django core code I found instances where an object (in one case `django.contrib.auth.User`) already existed.

I temporarily overrode `_fixture_setup()` to assert the db was clean prior to loading fixtures.  The assertion failed.

I was able to narrow the problem down to code that was in a `TestCase.setUpClass()` instead of `TestCase.setUp()`, and so the object was leaking out of the test and conflicting with other `TestCase` fixtures.

What I don't understand completely is I thought that the db was dropped and recreated between `TestCases` -- but perhaps that is not correct.

Update:  Recent version of Django includes `setUpTestData()` that should be used instead of `setUpClass()`

Comment: I'm experiencing the same with django 1.9. Isn't this a bug? shouldn't it be reported?

Comment: No, I think my assumption was just incorrect.  Note that I was accidentally creating an object in setUpClass() instead of setUp() ... so I was creating a model object in the wrong place.

Comment: I get the same problem, I assume each TestCase use a separate clean database, and load fixtures alone. if this is not true, how to make sure each testCase fixtures load order?

Comment: what's your final solution?

Comment: @ruandao  I moved object creation code out of setUpClass.